# Get the content of @renderBody() in Razor Templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way we can get content of @RenderBody() and print it using our extension on IHtmlHelper e.g.

```
<main>
    @Html.printBody()              
</main>
```

Here is extension

```
public static class Template
{        
    public static string printBody(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        return new HtmlString("content of @RenderBody()");
    }        
}
```

Comment: What version of MVC?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net Core, you're looking for the `BodyContent` property in the page.

In classic ASP.Net, you might be able to call `PageContext.BodyAction`.